# AppleScript error when running python script on import

Tags: macos, python-2.7, applescript, automator

I am trying to automate a python script with a keyboard shortcut. To do this, I am using the mac automator. In this, it runs this applescript:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    do shell script "python /Users/evettsam000/Desktop/myKeys.py"
    return input

end run
```

When I run it, it makes it to the python file, which starts by importing time, and then importing pyautogui. But there's an error when I run it from the automator, saying there's no module called pyautogui. However, when I run the python script by itself, it works. Is there any applescript command I can use to help this import? Thanks!

Comment: as for the python error, it sounds like your python installation doesn't have `pyautogui` installed, from a `Terminal` shell, try installing pyautogui into python with the command `pip install pyautogui`, if it's successful installing the module, try re-running your applescript.

Comment: I know I have that module installed, I did it a few days ago. Running the python script works manually in Idle and from the terminal. However, I did figure out a sorta messy solution. I changed the applescript to this, and it seemed to work:               tell application "Terminal"
 do script "cd ../../../../../../../..;cd Users/evettsam000/Desktop;python myKeys.py"
end tell